# Karma Webpack - Error: Cannot find module "./test/utilities.js"

Tags: javascript, karma-runner, webpack

I'm using Karma Webpack for the unit tests of a project.

When I run `karma start`, I have this error:

```
Error: Cannot find module "./test/utilities.js" at /myproject/test/campaign.test.js:49 <- webpack:///test/campaign.test.js:3:0
```

Here is the content of my file `campaign_test.js`:

```
"use strict";

var utilities = require('./test/utilities.js');

describe(" campaign unit tests", function () {
  var error = null;
  var user = null;

  utilities.initParse();  
});
```

Here is the `karma.conf.js` file:

```
var webpack = require("webpack"),
path = require("path");

// Karma configuration
// Generated on Mon May 11 2015 14:13:57 GMT-0600 (MDT)

module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: "test",
    frameworks: ["jasmine"],
    files: [
        "**/*.js"
    ],
    preprocessors: {
        "**/*.js": ["webpack",  "sourcemap"]
    },
    webpack: {
        plugins: [
            new webpack.ResolverPlugin([
                new webpack.ResolverPlugin.DirectoryDescriptionFilePlugin("bower.json", ["main"])
            ])
        ],
        resolve: {
            root: [path.join(__dirname, "./bower_components"), path.join(__dirname, "./src")]
        },
        devtool: "inline-source-map",
        resolve: {
            alias: {
                app: path.join(__dirname, 'test')
            }
        }
    },
    webpackMiddleware: {
        progress: false,
        stats: false,
        debug: true,
        noInfo: true,
        silent: true 
    },
    plugins: [
        require("karma-webpack"),
        require("karma-jasmine"),
        require("karma-phantomjs-launcher"),
        require("karma-sourcemap-loader"),
    ],
    reporters: ["dots"],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ["PhantomJS"],
    singleRun: false
  });
};
```

Here is the structure of my project:

```
package.json
karma.conf.js
test/
    campaign.test.js
    game.test.js
    user.test.js
    utilities.test.js
    utilities.js
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dependencies paths are relative to current script. So just rewrite your require statement:

```
var utilities = require('./utilities.js');
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I tried and now I've this error: `Fatal error: Path doesn't exist '/_karma_webpack_/utilities.js'`

Comment: In campaign.test.js? Or in another file?