# Mock exported function in module

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine, ecmascript-6

I have two modules which contain exported functions. "ModuleB" uses a function from "ModuleA". Now I want to test "ModuleB" and mock the used function from "ModuleA".

I use ES6 with babel. For testing I use karma and jasmine.

I tried using babel-rewire and inject-loader, but it just does not work. I'm kind of new to all this and I guess I'm just doing something wrong. So any help is appreciated!

**moduleA.js**

```
export function getResult() {
    return realResult;
}
```

**moduleB.js**

```
import * as ModuleA from './moduleA'

export function functionToTest() {
    let result = ModuleA.getResult();
    // do stuff with result which I want to test
}
```

**my test**

```
it("does the right thing", () => {
    // I tried using rewire, but this gives me an exception:
    ModuleB.__Rewire__('ModuleA', {

        getResult: () => {
            return fakeResult;
        }
    });

    let xyz = ModuleB.functionToTest(canvas, element);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who is interested in how it works with `babel-rewire`: The trick is to use `__RewireAPI__`.

```
import * as ModuleB from '../ModuleB'
import {__RewireAPI__ as ModuleBRewire} from '../ModuleA';

it("does the right thing", () => {
    let moduleAMock = {
        getResult: () => {
            return fakeResult;
        }
    }

    ModuleBRewire.__Rewire__('ModuleA', moduleAMock);

    let xyz = ModuleB.functionToTest();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look to this library https://www.npmjs.com/package/mockery I thought It's exactly what do you want. Hope it helps!

EDITED:

Basically you have to use mockery in each test to mock your function, the only problem is that you must use require against import with the modules you want to mock. Look this example:

```
const moduleUnderTest = './moduleB.js';
const moduleA_fake = { getResult: () => { return "This is a fake result"; } } ;

describe("Mocking functions", () => {

    it('Should be Fake Result', (done) => {

        mock.registerAllowable(moduleUnderTest);
        mock.registerMock('./moduleA.js', moduleA_fake);

        mock.enable({ useCleanCache: true });

        let ModuleB = require(moduleUnderTest);
        let res = ModuleB.functionToTest();

        res.should.be.eql("This is a fake result");


        mock.disable();
        mock.deregisterAll();

        done();
    });

    it('Should be Real Result', (done) => {

        let ModuleB = require(moduleUnderTest);
        let res = ModuleB.functionToTest();

        res.should.be.eql("real foo");

        done();
    });

});
```

You could see the complete example [Here](https://repl.it/Cjo4/0)

Comment: Can you  please give me an example how this works with es6?

Comment: Sure, Look this example I made for you, the tricky thing is the library was made it to be used with require, so in any test you want to mock a function you will have to call the module with require against import. [See Example](https://repl.it/Cjo4/0)

Comment: Thanks a lot! Now I understand how to use it. But I still have some trouble: I installed it via `npm install mockery` and created the `mock` via `let mock = require('mockery')`. When running the tests I get an error `ERROR in ./~/mockery/mockery.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'module'`. Any idea what this is?

Comment: Can you show me some code? It seems you are having problems with the way you are importing the module.. " ./~/ " this path won't ever exists in your computer.

Comment: Sure. The error occurs as soon as I create a test and try to get the module. I just wrote `describe("Mocking functions", () => {let mock = require('mockery'); }` The error I get is  `Error: Cannot find module "module" in C:/<cut this>/tests.webpack.js`. Maybe it's a problem with my webpack configuration? 

However, I finally found a way to use `babel-rewire`. Of course I'm curious how mockery works out, but I don't want to take too much of your time. If you have an idea why I get this error, please let me know. 
Otherwise I'll go in with babel-rewire. :)

Comment: It's ok, I'm glad to help you :), about the problem, I'm sure it should be something with the configuration of your Karma or Webpack because I can't reproduce the error, I'm using mocha with chai, so I guess it's a problem of configuration, Take a look to this errors, could help you out to find the problem: 

[Karma-Webpack-Error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33152927/karma-webpack-error-cannot-find-module-test-utilities-js)

[Karma Can't find module](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33933423/how-can-i-get-karma-webpack-to-find-the-module)